# is_rgb function in php

Tags: php, function, rgb

I need function what checks if value from $_GET is rgb value. What I am missing?

```
function is_rgb($val)
{
    return (bool)preg_match("/^(rgb(s*b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])bs*,s*b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])bs*,s*b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])bs*))|(rgb(s*(d?d%|100%)+s*,s*(d?d%|100%)+s*,s*(d?d%|100%)+s*))$/",
        $val);
}

if(!isset($_GET["header_bg_color"])) $header_bg_color = "E8F0F2";
else $header_bg_color = is_rgb($_GET["header_bg_color"]);
```

Comment: `is_rbg` returns `true` or `false`, and not the color, so if `header_bg_color` is set in `$_GET`, `$header_bg_color` is `true` and not the color that was passed.

Comment: Does `is_rgb` really need that complicated a regexp? You only need to check for a length of six characters with values 0-9/A-F

Answer (score 7):

**Hex validation function**

```
function validHex($hex) {
   return preg_match('/^#?(([a-f0-9]{3}){1,2})$/i', $hex);
}

$hex = '#FFFFFF';
if ( validHex($hex) ) {
   echo 'valid hex color';
}
else {
   echo 'invalid hex color';
}
```

**rgb validation function**

```
function validRgb($rgb) {
   return count($rgb) == 3 && is_numeric(implode($rgb)) && max($rgb) <= 255;
}

$rgb['r'] = '255';
$rgb['g'] = '255';
$rgb['b'] = '255';
if ( validRgb($rgb) ) {
   echo 'valid rgb color';
}
else {
   echo 'invalid rgb color';
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer here. Also +1 for knowing the difference between hex and rgb :)

Comment: Clever usage of `implode` and `max` for the RGB validation.

Answer (score 0):

This decides inside of the function and has a very simple regex.

```
function is_rgb($val) {
    if (preg_match('/^[A-F0-9]{6}$/', $val)) {
        //If valid return the rgb value if it is valid
        return $val;
    }
    else {
        return 'E8F0F2';
    }
}

$header_bg_color = is_rgb($_GET['header_bg_color']);
echo $header_bg_color;
```

This is also assuming that you are trying to accept ONLY an RGB value in the GET variable.